# Loop for getting selected Index

Tags: java, swing, loops, frame

i do have a **JList** and want to check if any **Index is selected or not**.
I thought it will work with a **loop**. I tried everything but everytime my whole **frame is blank**.
The JButton must **stay disabled until** any **Index is selected**.

```
  do {
    JButton.setEnabled(false);   
   } while (JList.getSelectedIndex() == -1);
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the language (Java?)

Comment: Pleas post a runnable example. If you want trigger an action depended on selection in list see the manual about by Oracle: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by adding a [`ListSelectionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/event/ListSelectionListener.html) to your `JList`. This is done via the [`addListSelectionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#addListSelectionListener-javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener-) method.

From the javadoc:

> Adds a listener to the list, to be notified each time a change to the
>   selection occurs; the preferred way of listening for selection state
>   changes. JList takes care of listening for selection state changes in
>   the selection model, and notifies the given listener of each change.
>   ListSelectionEvents sent to the listener have a source property set to
>   this list.